# Check if weekday is between weekdays in string

Tags: php, date, strtotime

So i have a list of weekdays in which i need to check if they are the current day. The list varies between either being 'Monday/Tuesday' and 'Wednesday - Friday'

My current solution is string comparison, so it only detects if the current weekday is written in the list item.

Heres the current solution (in PHP btw):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");
$day = get_sub_field('dag'); // the field containing the user input day
$currentDay = strftime('%a', mktime());
$currentDayLower = strtolower($currentDay);
$dayLowercase = strtolower($day);

$class = '';

if(strpos($dayLowercase, $currentDayLower) !== false ){
    $class = ' current-day';
} else{
    $class = '';
}
```

I was thinking about having an array of all weekdays and comparing the user field to current day position in the array, but im not sure if that would be efficient or even possible.

Is there any obvious or alternative method that could be easier than what I'm currently doing?

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I found a working solution, which i posted as an answer (I can't choose it as the answer for 2 days though). Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Can you show a real example of the list you are processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i found out, its rather complicated making a datetime from a Danish weekday string. A lot easier to go from English and format to Danish.

So i had to make it a bit different, by stitching parts of you guys' answers together.

```
<?php while ( have_rows('aabningstider_repeater', 'option') ) : the_row();
// vars
$day = get_sub_field('dag');
$timer = get_sub_field('aabne_timer');

$dayLower = strtolower($day);

$weekArray = array('mandag', 'tirsdag', 'onsdag', 'torsdag', 'fredag', 'lørdag', 'søndag' );
$dayArray = preg_split('/[\s,-]+/', $dayLower);

$today = date('w') - 1;

$class = '';

if(is_array($dayArray)){

    $days = [];
    foreach ($dayArray as $daySingle ) {
        array_push($days, array_search($daySingle, $weekArray));
    }

    if($today > $days[0] && $today < $days[1]){     
        $class = ' current-day in-between-days';

    } elseif($today == $days[0] || $today == $days[1]){
        $class = ' current-day';

    } else{
        $class = '';
    }
} 

endwhile; ?>
```

I'm pretty sure this will work untill i one day detect a major flaw. Until then it'll do.

Any feedback or optimization is greatly appreciated. And thanks for all the inputs!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your idea is feasible and it should not affect performance badly unless you do this many times in a short period of time, where *many* starts at a scale of hundreds of thousands. Notice that I have created an `array` of `$weekdays` and notice that when you assign a value for `$class`, that is an end sign for the cycle as well.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");
$day = get_sub_field('dag'); // the field containing the user input day
$dayLowercase = strtolower($day);
$weekdays = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday");

$class = '';

for ($index = 0, (!$class) && ($index < 5); $index++) {
    if(strpos($dayLowercase, $weekdays[$index]) !== false ){
        $class = ' current-day';
    } else{
        $class = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i probably should have specified. All this is in a while loop, looping through multiple day fields. It's for printing opening hours.

They would put in either:
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
etc...

Or:
Monday - Thursday
Friday
Saturday - Sunday

With your example every subject of the day field gets current-day class, if it contains a weekday.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the range of days includes the current day, you can do the following.

```
$period = 'Wednesday-Friday';
$limitDays = explode('-', $period);
$startDayName = trim(strtolower($limitDays[0]));
$endDayName = trim(strtolower($limitDays[1]));

$today = new DateTime();
$todayName = strtolower($today->format('l'));

// Check if the startDay or endDay is today.
echo "$startDayName $endDayName $todayName\n";
if ($startDayName === $todayName || $endDayName === $todayName) {
    echo "Same day\n";
    $class = 'current-day';
} else {
    // Get a date time representing the start day.
    $startDay = new \DateTime();
    $startDay->modify("next $startDayName");

    // Based on the start day, get the next current day.
    $thisDay = new \DateTime();
    $thisDay->modify("next $startDayName");
    $thisDay->modify("next $todayName");

    // Based on the start day, get the next end day.
    $endDay = new \DateTime();
    $endDay->modify("next $startDayName");
    $endDay->modify("next $endDayName");

    // Check if thisDay is between the startDay and endDay.
    if ($startDay < $thisDay && $thisDay < $endDay) {
        $class = 'current-day';
    } else {
        $class = '';
    }
}
echo $class . "\n";
```

I'm not sure that this is easier or more efficient, but it's not a bad way to do this.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. Unfortunately the user input is in Danish and as far as i was able to gather, converting a local language string of a weekday into a timestamp is near impossible unless you do it manually for every weekday. I was able to convert your method into an array of weekdays, and using array_search to find the weekdays position in the array. Might be a bit of a hack, but so far its working out.

Answer (score -1):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "danish");
$day = get_sub_field('dag'); // the field containing the user input day

$currentDayLower = strtolower(date("D"));
$dayLowercase = strtolower($day);

$class = '';

if($dayLowercase === $currentDayLower)
   $class = ' current-day';
```

Comment: If you have day in the formats 'Monday/Tuesday' and 'Wednesday - Friday', First expload those in a variable $day_list='Monday/Tuesday';
$day_array=explode("/",$day_list); and then use if (in_array(date("D"), $number_list)) $class = ' current-day';

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)